# Get exact string from html using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a list of excercises in Latex, written inside strings. I wrote a script in php to generate a list of exercises, using:

```
<button type = "button" onclick = "aggiornaInfo()">Save</button>
       <?php
            $exercises = array(
              "$$\\int_0^1 x^2\\,dx$$",
              "Evaluate $$\\int_{-1}^1 e^x\\,dx$$",
              "Evaluate $$\\int cos(x)\\,dx$$"
            );
        
            $n = 3;
            for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++){
                echo "<li><select id='points'>";
                for($j = 0; $j <= 10; $j += 0.5){
                    echo "<option value='$j'>$j</option><br>";
                }
                echo"</select><input type='checkbox' name='item' value='Exercise " . $i + 1 . "' id = 'checkbox1' style='display: inline-block;'>&emsp;" . $exercises[$i] . "<br></li><br><hr>";
            }
        ?>
```

Note that the exercises are both only LaTex (surrounded by double dollar) and also text and LaTex.
My goal is to write the problems i wrote inside a rmd file, and i'm half way but i have found a problem.
I found the way to get the string of every exercise I choose with the checkbox, but when i'm printing it,it will return something i don't want:

Result i want: `"$$\\int_0^1 x^2\\,dx$$"`

Result i get: `'00.511.522.533.544.555.566.577.588.599.510 ∫10x2dx∫01x2dx\\int_0^1 x^2\\,dx'`

This is my javascript code:

```
function aggiornaInfo() {
  var items = document.getElementsByName("item");
  var checkedItems = [];
  
  
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].checked) {
      var itemName = items[i];
      item = itemName.parentElement.textContent.trim();
      checkedItems.push(item);
    }
  }
  text += checkedItems.join("\n");
  console.log(checkedItems);
```

Summarizing, i want the exact same string, not a modified one.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: You are getting the text content of the parent `li`, that includes not only the checkbox and the text you put after it - but the select field as well. And the options of that, also have text content.

Comment: Also the HTML is invalid. You have BRs inside the ULs

Comment: `value='Exercise " . $i + 1 . "'` - what is the point of that, you don't appear to be using that anywhere? Why don't you put your _actual_ exercise into the value to begin with - then you would just have to _get_ the value of the checkbox, and not fish around for the value you need in the surrounding DOM ...

Comment: @CBroe that's the way. Thank you, didn't thought about that. The previous value was used for another piece of code, but i can re-write it in a different way. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example where I fixed the HTML and wrapped the text in a label

I also use recommended eventListeners

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click", () => {
    const checkedItems = [...document.querySelectorAll("[name=item]:checked")]
      .map(item => item.nextSibling.textContent);
    if (checkedItems.length === 0) return;
    // here you have the array
    console.log(checkedItems.join("\n"));
  });
});
```

```html
<button type="button" id="save">Save</button>
<ul>
  <li>
    <select id='points'>
      <option value='0'>0</option><br>
      <option value='0.5'>0.5</option><br>
      <option value='1'>1</option><br>
      <option value='1.5'>1.5</option><br>
      <option value='2'>2</option><br>
      <option value='2.5'>2.5</option><br>
      <option value='3'>3</option><br>
      <option value='3.5'>3.5</option><br>
      <option value='4'>4</option><br>
      <option value='4.5'>4.5</option><br>
      <option value='5'>5</option><br>
      <option value='5.5'>5.5</option><br>
      <option value='6'>6</option><br>
      <option value='6.5'>6.5</option><br>
      <option value='7'>7</option><br>
      <option value='7.5'>7.5</option><br>
      <option value='8'>8</option><br>
      <option value='8.5'>8.5</option><br>
      <option value='9'>9</option><br>
      <option value='9.5'>9.5</option><br>
      <option value='10'>10</option><br>
    </select><label><input type='checkbox' name='item' value='Exercise 1' id='checkbox1' style='display: inline-block;'>&emsp;$$\int_0^1 x^2\,dx$$</label>
    <hr>
  </li>
  <hr>
  <li>
    <select id='points'>
      <option value='0'>0</option><br>
      <option value='0.5'>0.5</option><br>
      <option value='1'>1</option><br>
      <option value='1.5'>1.5</option><br>
      <option value='2'>2</option><br>
      <option value='2.5'>2.5</option><br>
      <option value='3'>3</option><br>
      <option value='3.5'>3.5</option><br>
      <option value='4'>4</option><br>
      <option value='4.5'>4.5</option><br>
      <option value='5'>5</option><br>
      <option value='5.5'>5.5</option><br>
      <option value='6'>6</option><br>
      <option value='6.5'>6.5</option><br>
      <option value='7'>7</option><br>
      <option value='7.5'>7.5</option><br>
      <option value='8'>8</option><br>
      <option value='8.5'>8.5</option><br>
      <option value='9'>9</option><br>
      <option value='9.5'>9.5</option><br>
      <option value='10'>10</option><br>
    </select><label><input type='checkbox' name='item' value='Exercise 2' id='checkbox1' style='display: inline-block;'>&emsp;Evaluate $$\int_{-1}^1 e^x\,dx$$</label>
    <hr>
  </li>

  <li>
    <select id='points'>
      <option value='0'>0</option><br>
      <option value='0.5'>0.5</option><br>
      <option value='1'>1</option><br>
      <option value='1.5'>1.5</option><br>
      <option value='2'>2</option><br>
      <option value='2.5'>2.5</option><br>
      <option value='3'>3</option><br>
      <option value='3.5'>3.5</option><br>
      <option value='4'>4</option><br>
      <option value='4.5'>4.5</option><br>
      <option value='5'>5</option><br>
      <option value='5.5'>5.5</option><br>
      <option value='6'>6</option><br>
      <option value='6.5'>6.5</option><br>
      <option value='7'>7</option><br>
      <option value='7.5'>7.5</option><br>
      <option value='8'>8</option><br>
      <option value='8.5'>8.5</option><br>
      <option value='9'>9</option><br>
      <option value='9.5'>9.5</option><br>
      <option value='10'>10</option><br>
    </select><label><input type='checkbox' name='item' value='Exercise 3' id='checkbox1' style='display: inline-block;'>&emsp;Evaluate $$\int cos(x)\,dx$$</label>
    <hr>
  </li>

</ul>
```

The corrected PHP:

```php
for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++){
  echo "<li><select id='points'>";
  for($j = 0; $j <= 10; $j += 0.5){
    echo "<option value='$j'>$j</option>";
  }
  echo"</select><label><input type='checkbox' name='item' value='Exercise " . $i + 1 . "' id = 'checkbox1' style='display: inline-block;'>&emsp;" . $exercises[$i] . "</label><hr></li>";
}
```